# How to combine high voltage and high current source?

Tags: high-voltage, parallel, generator, high-current, high-power

Can whimshurst machine (high voltage and low current) and homopolar generator (high current and low voltage) be connected in parallel to draw high watts?
Please explain the process & flow of charge carriers, please don't use laws governing the process.

Comment: "*... please don't use laws governing the process.*" What do you mean? "*Can ...  be connected in parallel to draw high watts?*" Are you hoping to get more power than the sum of the two individual powers? (Can you see where this is going or is this why you don't want to hear about laws?)

Comment: Two devices connected in parallel must have the same voltage.

Comment: Short answer - No ,they can't.  If one power supply is spec'd at 1 million volts & 1 uA, and another power supply is spec'd at 1 uV and 1 million amps, connecting them together will not provide 1 million amps @ 1 million volts.

Comment: @transistor when I look for the answer on google they mention laws like ohm laws, and terms like impedance which confuses me more, I want to know the process, what actually happens at the level of electrons or charge carriers?

Comment: @SteveSh That's what I want to understand, why does that happen? What happens at level of electrons? At the point of junction where two sources are connected in parallel, why don't high speed electrons (high current) reach the appliance and appliance can count large electrons pool (high voltage) from two different sources connected in parallel?

Comment: Dear Yogie. to start off: this is nor an education forum, thus we do no explain the laws of physics. You admit having difficulties with ohm laws, and terms like impedance.  However next you ask *"What happens at level of electrons? "* which gets us into the realm of physics at its basic level: quantum physics. I have two degrees but even I struggle to understand a lot of what is happening there. So I don't think explanations at that level are useful to you. As to "laws governing the process" I am afraid that is at the core of all things electronic. We can't do without those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for physics answers and not EE answers i.e. it's better suited on another site.

Comment: I don't know what 'whimshurst machine' or 'homopolar generator' means so can't answer but two devices in parallel will see the same voltage so it sounds unlikely I would expect one or other to be damaged.

Answer (score 2):

Power is the *product* of voltage and current, specified as a law (Ohm's law) as

- W (power) = E (voltage) * I (current).

You've given examples of high current and low voltage, low current and high voltage, but both are low power because they're a large value times a small value.

To get high power, you need to make the product E * I be a large value.

So what is current, anyway? It's the flow of charge. And voltage? Potential of charge difference, sometimes called 'tension'. A large amount of power is the large flow of charge with a large change in potential difference. And to release that power, that flow has to happen across a *resistance*, giving the more familiar form of Ohm's law:

- E (voltage) = I (current) * R (resistance)

And its corollary:

- W (power) = I^2 (current squared) * R (resistance)

Conversely, if you have a conductor of infinitely low resistance, and a large current flow, you don't dissipate any power in the conductor. An example of this are the superconducting magnets used in MRI machines: they are 'charged' with a current which circulates nearly endlessly in the magnet coils. That power isn't dissipated until the magnet is 'quenched': an external load is inserted on the coil, and the stored power shed as heat. This is necessary to perform maintenance on the magnet, or when something like this happens:

[image]

from here: https://www.wired.com/2007/01/strange-attract/

Comment: A chair stuck to a magnet is one thing, I've had a fork-lift truck stuck to one. It was manoeuvring the GRP patient transport tube into the magnet, with the field on, 'cos it takes too long to run the field down.

Comment: That must have been scary. Any link to the story?

Comment: Funnily enough, we kept it quiet at the time. Eventually a number of big employees used a few 4 be 2s to lever it off. It was a long time ago, so neither the innocent nor the guilty should be embarrassed by the telling now. It wasn't so much scary, there was nobody between the magnet and the FLT, but there were a few [ohno](http://acronymsandslang.com/definition/7769536/Ohno-second-meaning.html) seconds between realising what was going to happen, and the clunk as it did happen.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to combine a Wimshurst and a homopolar generator. Let's say the first delivers 1 MV and 1 μA, the second delivers 100 mV and 1000 A, both into a suitable load of course.

In series. The voltages add, to get 1,000,000.1 V, the current is limited to 1 μA by the Wimshurst.

In parallel. The currents add, to get 1,000.000001 A, while the low impedance of the homopolar reduces the total voltage to 100 mV